# how to create xml file from Html form using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following Html format,

```
 <title>Registration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS_LABs.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
```

PersonID: 
   First Name: 
    Last Name:
    DOB: 
   Gender:

```
</div>
</body>
</html>

   I want create person.xml file in D:\\ or any specified drive using javascript
```

as
and save records in that file.
Thnx in advance.......

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can give JavaScript full read/write access to local drives. Even if you could, I don't think you should. It'd be too easy to tamper with the code and write jut about anything anywhere. The exact reason why you can't allow full read/write access for JavaScript on local files.

Try to look into some server side solution.